# How do I run a JS file (with JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm following a tutorial on how to build a game with WebSockets. However, I don't know how to test my code; it says that localhost doesn't work. Can you explain to me why it's not working?
(code)

```
const http = require("http")
const websocketServer = require("websocket").server
const httpServer = http.createServer();
httpServer.listen(9090, () => console.log("Listrening... on 9090"))
// hashmap
const clients = {}

const wsServer = new websocketServer({
    "httpServer": httpServer
})
wsServer.on("request", request => {
    // connect
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    connection.on("open", () => console.log("opened!"))
    connection.on("closed", () => console.log("closed!"))
    connection.on("message", message => {
        const result =  JSON.parse(message.utf8Data)
        // i have recieved a message from the client
        console.log(result)
    })

    // generate a new clientId
    const clientId = guid();
    clients[clientId] = {
        "connection": connection
    }

    const payLoad = {
        "method": "connect",
        "clientId": clientid
    }
    // send back the client connect
    connection.send(JSON.stringify(payLaod))

})



function S4() {
    return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
}
 
// then to call it, plus stitch in '4' in the third group
const guid = () => (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0,3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
```

Thanks for your help!
(sorry if this is a stupid question - I'm very new to game dev w/ javascript)

¡Adios!

Comment: what is your browser(client)-side code? that's only a server

Comment: This looks like server-side code to me, so you can try starting it with node. `node yourfile.js` if this code is in a file named "yourfile.js". See for instance [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-and-run-your-first-program-in-node-js). If this is client-side code,  you need to open it in a browser. However, for proper connection with srever, you need to _host_ the page on a webserver locally, _and_ have the server part running as well (locally on another port) that would be the correct test.

Comment: " it says that localhost doesn't work", what does it say exactly? What is "it"?

Comment: read this to be able to implement a client-side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications ; this might be important: `Most browsers now only allow secure WebSocket connections, and no longer support using them in insecure contexts`

Comment: @Pac0 the screen

Comment: @Pac0 I want to test the server out before I implement client-side code

Comment: @Sianny : I guess the screen didn't suddenly start saying things all by itself. You got _some_ message on the screen (which :**exact** message, I'm sure it's not "localhost doesn't work"). This message appeared after _you attempted something_. How did you try to run this, what caused the message to appear?

Comment: @Pac0 I was using visual studio code as my text editor. So pressed start debugging. It took me to localhost:8080. And the screen displayed a message saying: 'This site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect.' e.t.c

Comment: @SiannaZewdie ok, that's very useful. I could therefore recommend to try [this guide from the Visual Studio Code site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial). It should help you get started on how to run a local server running javascript files with node.js.